# Getting SharePoint Site Title

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sharepoint-2010, .net-4.0

I've having difficulty following this guide

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/sharepoint-client-object-model-sites.html

I've created the helper class as advised:

```
namespace TestSharepoint
{
  public class SharepointHelper
  {
    private ClientContext clientContext;
    private Web rootWeb;

    public SharepointHelper(string url, string username, string password)
    {
      clientContext = new ClientContext(url);
      var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "oshirowanen.com");
      clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
      rootWeb = clientContext.Web;
      clientContext.Load(rootWeb);
    }
  }
}
```

However, I do not want to create another site, as I already have a site, so I wanted to test the next part by retrieving the existing sites title:

```
public Web GetWebByTitle(string siteTitle)
{
  var query = clientContext.LoadQuery(
    rootWeb.Webs.Where(p => p.Title == siteTitle));
  clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
  return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and added this to the form load event:

```
var sh = new SharepointHelper("https://sharepoint.oshirowanen.com/sites/oshirodev/", "sharepoint_admin_user", "sharepoint_admin_password");
var w = sh.GetWebByTitle("Oshirowanen SharePoint");
Console.WriteLine(w.Title);
```

What I am getting confused about is, why I am typing in the title of the site which I want to receive the title of???  So I think I am not using this properly?

The error I get is:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SharePointProgramming.exe

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

The username and password I have used has full SharePoint privileges.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, C#, .NET 4.0, and SharePoint 2010.

Comment: make sure that "Oshirowanen SharePoint" is a subweb of site collection /sites/oshirodev/. If "Oshirowanen SharePoint" = rootWeb than in won't be visible in rootWeb.Webs collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the title of the site your just need the value of the variable web.title.

```
  namespace TestSharepoint
{
  public class SharepointHelper
  {
    private ClientContext clientContext;
    private Web rootWeb;

    public SharepointHelper(string url, string username, string password)
    {
      clientContext = new ClientContext(url);
      var credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password, "oshirowanen.com");
      clientContext.Credentials = credentials;
      rootWeb = clientContext.Web;
      clientContext.Load(rootWeb,web=>web.title);
    clientContent.ExecuteQuery();
    string siteTitle=web.title;
            }
          }
        }
```